# Setting "limit" in folder-hook

Tags: email, mutt

I'm trying to use "limit" by default when entering given mail folder. So far the only solution I found was using push, like:

```
folder-hook rss 'push "l!~R<enter>"'
```

But that just seems wrong - going all the way through keyboard buffer just to run a command, not to mention that it will fail if I'll remap "l" to some other command.

Is there a better way? I tried using `folder-hook rss 'limit "!~R"'` but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some digging, and apparently the correct way is to use push, but instead of letter, providing function name in "<...>".

So, the folder-hook line should look like:

```
folder-hook rss 'push <limit>!~R<enter>'
```